# How to create a dataframe from a single row of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to create a dataframe from a select row of another dataframe, e.g.,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [0, 1]})

# I want to create df1 such that df1 is a dataframe from the first row of df
df1 = df.iloc[0] # produces a pandas Series which is not what i want
```

This one seems to work but seems to involve a lot of (unnecessary?) ops?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0]).T
```

Comment: You could use a list (or a slice) to index: `df.iloc[[0]]`. Series also have `.to_frame()`

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Ah I see. What does the interior brackets do here?

Comment: the interior bracket means a list `[0]`, not a single integer `0`. When you slice with a list, you get a dataframe. When you slice with an integer, you get a series.